# Is it possible to programmatically determine if the CUDA profiler is running?

Tags: cuda, profiler

The problem I'm trying to solve.  Most of our command line apps, when run from Visual Studio, we like to force the user to hit a key to exit, so we can see the output in Visual Studio while we're debugging.

This doesn't work at all with profiling.  One way to fix that would be to determine if the profiler was running or not.

The API to the CUDA profiler is rather limited:
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__PROFILER.html

It appears to support:

- Initialization `cudaProfilerInitialize`
- Starting `cudaProfilerStart`
- Stopping `cudaProfilerStop`

But no way to determine if it's actually running?

Answer (score 3):

Well, an ugly and surely sub-optimal solution is just searching for nvprof among the running processes...

On Linux, you can do this with `readproc()`:

```
#include <proc/readproc.h>

proc_t* readproc(PROCTAB *PT, proc_t *return_buf);
```

For more information on how to use the functions in `readproc.h`, have a look at:

[How does the ps command work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/262177/34868)

on SuperUser.com, and particularly at [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405328/34868).

**Note:** Don't forget nvprof might be running but not profiling *your* process.

Comment: Yeah, we run on windoze, but the basic principles apply.  For the use case I have in mind, being a bit slow is okay.  Clearly clunky, but it works.  Holding out for another answer...